# Scraping categories and subcategories using beautifulsoup

Tags: beautifulsoup, electron

I am trying to retrieve all categories and subcategories within a website. I am able to use BeautifulSoup to pull every single product in the category once I am in it. However, I am struggling with the loop for categories. I'm using this as a test website: http://www.shophive.com.

How do I loop through each category as well as the subcategories on the left side of the website? I would like to extract all products within the category/subcategory and display on my page.

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import user_agent
import requests

useragent = user_agent.generate_user_agent(device_type='desktop')
headers = {'User-Agent': useragent}
req = requests.get('http://www.shophive.com/', headers=headers)
html = req.text


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

main_category_links = []
for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='parentMenu arrow'):
    main_category_links.append(soup.find('a').get('href'))

print(main_category_links)

subcategory_links = []
for link in soup.find_all('a', class_='itemMenuName'):
    subcategory_links.append(link.get('href'))

print(subcategory_links)
```

I'll break this down for you piece by piece.

```
useragent = user_agent.generate_user_agent(device_type='desktop')
headers = {'User-Agent': useragent}
req = requests.get('http://www.shophive.com/', headers=headers)
html = req.text
```

Here we just make the request and store the HTML. I use a module called "user_agent" to generate a User Agent to use in the headers, just my preference.

```
<div class="parentMenu arrow">
<a href="http://www.shophive.com/year-end-clearance-sale">
<span>New Year's Clearance Sale</span>
</a>
</div>
```

The links for the main categories are stored like so, so in order to extract just the links we do this:

```
main_category_links = []
for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='parentMenu arrow'):
    main_category_links.append(soup.find('a').get('href'))
```

We iterate over the results of `soup.find_all('div', class_='parentMenu arrow')` since elements the links we want are children of these elements. Then we append `soup.find('a').get('href')` to our list of main category links. We use `soup.find` this time because we only want one result, then we get the contents of the href.

```
<a class="itemMenuName level1" href="http://www.shophive.com/apple/mac">
<span>Mac / Macbooks</span>
</a>
```

The subcategories are stored like this, notice the "a" tag has a class this time, this makes it a little easier for us to find it.

```
subcategory_links = []
for link in soup.find_all('a', class_='itemMenuName'):
    subcategory_links.append(link.get('href'))
```

Here we iterate over `soup.find_all('a', class_='itemMenuName')`. When you search for classes in BeautifulSoup, you can just search for *part* of the class name. This is helpful to us in this case since the class name varies from `itemMenuName level1` to `itemMenuName level2`. These elements have the link inside of them already, so we just extract the contents of the href that holds the URL with `link.get('href')` and append it to our list of subcategory links.

Comment: Thank you sir .
Now i want to scrape filters and do it but there is problem with that but same problem with sub filters.For example i click on apple category 
it will display only filter names not its value what should i do scrape its value